# Member of team in iTunes Connect, but still not enough for test with TestFlight

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-developer

I want to invite people to test an app with TestFlight.

A client invited me to iTunes Connect with the organisation email. 
In iTunes Connect I see that:

[image]

So, there is no way to add an app here.

I am thinking of Apple Developer, because the Apple ID was automatically created with the invite to iTunes Connect, and I am seeing this:

[image]

This is completely different from another account that I use, where I am member of a team.

So, my questions:

Do I need to have a paid developer account for testing with TestFlight, besides the invite to iTunes Connect?

I have to tell my client that he has to add me as a team member to Apple Developer?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to have a paid developer account for testing with
>   TestFlight, besides the invite to iTunes Connect?

No, no need to pay $99 and get an Apple dev account for test-flight testing.

> I have to tell my client that he has to add me as a team member to Apple Developer?

I assume that, apparently your client given you a role which is restricted to create a new app record. i.e You should be either Admin or Agent to create an App record.

[Know more about Roles and Responsibilities of iTunes connect member centre](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/).